# Response time spiking in Rails 4 / Puma app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, puma

We're seeing some odd behavior on a Rails 4.0 (Ruby 2.0.0) app that was recently deployed.  I am NOT on Heroku, but rather EC2 instances. The app uses puma and hipache to serve the requests.

For the most part, the app is very fast and averages about 20ms response times. However once it hits a certain amount of RPM, response times spike dramatically. I am using New Relic to track response times and this is a graph of this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAIgT.png

You can see that the throughput is not even that high, but a certain level, something is breaking down.  I'm not an expert at the puma configuration but have tried playing with different numbers of workers and threads and it hasn't seemed to help at all.

We have a high volume app on EC2 running great with Rails3/Ruby1.9.3/Unicorn, and I'm regretting not using what I know works, but at this point, I can't go back to Rails3 so if this is ringing any bells with anyone out there I'd love a few things to try.